# JSPDF - display hand signature from canvas

Tags: jquery, canvas, jspdf

How can I get a hand drawn signature onto the PDF?
I have a jquery mobile report which the customer signs at the end. After the signature is drawn on the canvas it is displayed back to the customer.

I am then converting the report to PDF using JSPdf. I am displaying text, tables, and a logo with no problem, but this signature thing has really stumped me.
With a normal pic you just convert to a URI and the pic is displayed but all I am getting with the signature is the URI.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HNBL.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use signaturepad.js jQuery plugin to generate base64 coded signature image.
Use that code as image src in htmltopdf in jspdf

[signaturepad.js documentation](https://github.com/thomasjbradley/signature-pad)

Answer (score 1):

The answer was as simple as finding the generated image. Thank you once again.

```
var SigImg = document.getElementById("sig-image");
doc.addImage(SigImg, 'png', 20, 20, 100, 40)
```

Comment: I knw its a bit offtopic but how did you managed styling the html rendered in a PDF using jspdf?..I am finding it difficult to style the contents that are rendered...any suggestion?